# value toArray is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have got a problem when I tired to compile my scala program. Here's my code.

This is the part of the code giving out problem.

```
val Average_Age = 
 value2
  .groupBy(_._2._1)
  .mapValues(Sum_Age=>mean1(Sum_Age.map(_._2._2)))
  .toArray
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark has mainly two types of Operations on RDD:

1. **Transformations**: Takes input as RDD and outputs as RDD
2. **Actions**: Takes input RDD and returns a Scala Collection.

What you are doing wrong here is you are trying to convert the `RDD` into the `Array` directly. That can't be done hence you need to apply the Action first to get the output in form of scala Collection.

Hence , you can make this work by adding an action :

```
val Average_Age = 
 value2
  .groupBy(_._2._1)
  .mapValues(Sum_Age=>mean1(Sum_Age.map(_._2._2))).collect
  .toArray
```

P.S.: The code is not tested !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with Spark and working with RDDs (Resilient Distributed Dataset), but in case you're not, [some reading](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#more-on-rdd-operations) would be really helpful.

Problem in your case is that `RDD` no longer supports directly invoking `toArray()`; you should use `.collect()` instead.